Can I create an excel spreadsheet, on android phone using android studio, even if user doesn't have utilities like WPS already installed?
Currently I'm developing a Personal Finance android application. I wish to provide user with a detailed report about his/her expenses in an excel spreadsheet, although I've integrated Firebase Database with my android app, So, even if it's not possible to perform CRUD activities solely using Java, Is there a way by using Firebase I can generate spreadsheet? Or is there any other way I can gain desired output?
I've coded a Java-Excel code which can perform CRUD operations. Though I'm not completely sure if I can achieve precise results, if the code is generated on a device which is not using utilities like 'WPS-Office' or as such.

You can generate excel file yourself check this guide:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-excel
But in general pdf is more desirable format for reports
